# How many times I can reschedule the Sitecore certification exam?

Tags: training-certification

I have already registered for Sitecore certification exam. I need to reschedule it, but I  have doubt on the allowed number of times for rescheduling process.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I took the exam it didn't appear to be a limit on how many times you can reschedule, there is however a time period when the purchase expires anyway and you need to take the exam by that date.

The only thing that was mentioned regarding rescheduling was:

> I understand that if I do reschedule or cancel my registration with
> less than 24 hours notice, I will be required to pay an additional
> fee.

You can take a look at the KB article https://kryterion.force.com/support/s/article/How-to-Avoid-Exam-Rescheduling-Cancellation-Fees?language=en_US

Comment: Thanks  for your reply, I understand that we should take exam with in expire date (3 months) but  I need to know within this 3 months how many time I can reschedule it.

Comment: In order to receive an official answer I would suggest you contact training@sitecore.net for any questions related to invoicing or your webassessor, in my case it was OLPsupport@KryterionOnline.com. If you have your account setup you can take a look at the help page https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=help&tabs=1

Comment: You can reschedle it twice only. Post that reschedule button gets disabled so it wont even alow resheduling with additonal cost after scheduling two time.

Answer (score 2):

You can reschedule your exam twice only. After 2 rescedules, the reschedule button gets disabled so it won't even allow rescheduling, even with additional cost.

Answer (score 1):

You can reschedule a Sitecore certification exam from the `Scheduled Exam` page on the `Webassessor portal`, where you can view a list of all your exams. In the Details column, you will find the Reschedule/Cancel link.

For online exams, you can reschedule up to 24 hours before the scheduled time without any additional cost. For testing center exams, you can reschedule up to 72 hours before the scheduled time without incurring extra charges. However, if you need to reschedule within 24 hours for an online exam or 72 hours for a testing center exam, a late fee will apply.

For more detailed information, you can refer to the link provided.

> https://kryterion.my.site.com/support/s/article/How-to-reschedule-cancel-your-assessment?language=en_US